# pd.to_csv exports mixed int/str content as float despite explicit declaration as dtype=object

Tags: python, pandas

In the following example, `good` and `bad` are created to have identical content, but only one of them gets exported to CSV in the way that I want:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> good = pd.Series({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': ''})
>>> good
a    1
b    2
c
dtype: object
>>> good.to_csv()
',0\na,1\nb,2\nc,\n'  # ok

>>> bad = pd.Series({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': float('nan')}).fillna('')
>>> bad
a    1
b    2
c
dtype: object
>>> bad.to_csv()
',0\na,1.0\nb,2.0\nc,\n'  # ???
```

I am aware that pandas [does not support mixed int/nan Series and thus auto-promotes them to float](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#nan-integer-na-values-and-na-type-promotions), however both Series here claim to have dtype object already!

What is especially frustrating here is that the printed data differs crucially from the exported data, with the `pandas.DataFrame.to_string` function (called by `print`) respecting the dtype while the `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` function not doing it.

Another example of the same thing:

```
>>> row1 = pd.Series({'a': 1, 'b': 2}, dtype=object)
>>> row2 = pd.Series({'b': 2, 'c': 3}, dtype=object)
>>> pd.DataFrame([row1, row2], dtype=object).fillna('').to_csv()
',a,b,c\n0,1,2,\n1,,2,3\n'  # ok

>>> row1['a'] = 42
>>> pd.DataFrame([row1, row2], dtype=object).fillna('').to_csv()
',a,b,c\n0,1,42,\n1,,2,3\n'  # ok

>>> row1['b'] = 42
>>> pd.DataFrame([row1, row2], dtype=object).fillna('').to_csv()
',a,b,c\n0,42,42,\n1,,2,3\n'  # ok

>>> row1[['a', 'b']] = [42, 42]
>>> pd.DataFrame([row1, row2], dtype=object).fillna('').to_csv()
',a,b,c\n0,42.0,42.0,\n1,,2.0,3\n'  # ???
```

Is there any justification for `row1[['a', 'b']] = [42, 42]` having different behavior from `row1['a'] = 42; row1['b'] = 42`? How can I avoid accidental float conversions generally?

Versions used: Python 3.7, pandas 1.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really address the "why" part, but I found a work-around for my specific situation. I think attempting to avoid "spoiling" the DataFrame is a fruitless task, so I just patch up my DataFrame right before exporting it:

```py
df_fixed = df.applymap(lambda cell: int(cell) if str(cell).endswith('.0') else cell)
```

```
>>> df.to_csv()
',a,b,c\n0,42.0,42.0,\n1,,2.0,3\n'

>>> df_fixed.to_csv()
',a,b,c\n0,42,42,\n1,,2,3\n'
```